# Getting user temporary folder path in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, path, directory

How I can get the user's temp folder path in C++? My program has to run on Windows Vista and XP and they have different temp paths. How I can get it without losing compatibility?

Comment: If you're only interested in windows solutions you should place that in your question title.

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to f-roche's, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702008/3543437

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use the Win32 GetTempPath API?

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992(VS.85).aspx

This API is available starting with W2K and hence will be available on all of your listed targets.

Comment: `GetTempPath()` has been around a lot longer than W2K. It existed in Win95.

Answer (score 16):

Since C++ 17 you can use a cross-platform function:
`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path()`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path

Comment: `std::filesystem::temp_directory_path().wstring()` works like a charm!

Comment: Well... kind of. I was hoping it would return whatever `TEMP` was set to, but it does more behind the scenes (but for your own good). For example, I've got a UWP Unit Test app, and it returns this instead: `L"C:\\Users\\user name\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\$(GUID)\\AC\\Temp\\$(FileName)"` Which is the more useful of the two possibilities, seeing as a UWP app wouldn't let you write directly to whatever is set to `TEMP` in your env-vars with something like `fwrite`, which I manually verified is in fact the case.

Answer (score 6):

The GetTempPath function retrieves the path of the directory designated for temporary files. This function supersedes the GetTempDrive function.

```
DWORD GetTempPath(

DWORD nBufferLength, // size, in characters, of the buffer 
LPTSTR lpBuffer // address of buffer for temp. path 
);
```

**Parameters**

`nBufferLength`

Specifies the size, in characters, of the string buffer identified by lpBuffer.

`lpBuffer`

Points to a string buffer that receives the null-terminated string specifying the temporary file path.

**Return Values**

If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in characters, of the string copied to lpBuffer, not including the terminating null character. If the return value is greater than nBufferLength, the return value is the size of the buffer required to hold the path. 
If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

**Remarks**

The GetTempPath function gets the temporary file path as follows:

1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable, if TMP is not defined.
3. The current directory, if both TMP and TEMP are not defined.

Comment: You should link to an MSDN documentation as opposed to copy and apsting the contents

Comment: I'd actually appreciate both the info AND the link. The problem with links is that they rot over time.

Comment: -1 for giving no indication that it's a quotation, for not citing the source of the quotation, and for pasting out-of-date information.

Comment: This will usually return `C:\Windows\Temp` for Win32 apps and the temporary storage location for Windows Store Apps for AppContainers, and is also what std's filesystem `temp_directory_path()` api will return. Personally, I'd rather use the std instead of mucking around directly with WinAPIs, but a mature `<filesystem>` wasn't around when this was answered initially.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10, this can be tricky because the value of the Temporary Path depends not only what it's set to by default, but also what kind of app you're using. So it depends what specifically you need.

### [Common Area] TEMP in User's Local App Data

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <Shlobj_core.h>
#include <string_view>
// ...
static void GetUserLocalTempPath(std::wstring& input_parameter) {
    static constexpr std::wstring_view temp_label = L"\\Temp\\";
    HWND folder_handle = { 0 };
    WCHAR temp_path[MAX_PATH];
    auto get_folder = SHGetFolderPath( 
        folder_handle, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_DEFAULT, temp_path
    );
    if (get_folder == S_OK) {
        input_parameter = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(temp_path);
        input_parameter.append(temp_label);
        CloseHandle(folder_handle);
    }
}
```

`GetUserLocalTempPath` will likely return the full name instead of the short name.
Also, if whatever is running it is doing it as as SYSTEM instead of a logged in user, instead of it returning `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`, it will return something more like, `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp`

### Temp for whatever the TEMP environment variable is

```
#include <Windows.h>
// ...
static void GetEnvTempPath(std::wstring& input_parameter) {
    wchar_t * env_var_buffer = nullptr;
    std::size_t size = 0;
    if ( _wdupenv_s(&env_var_buffer, &size, L"TEMP") == 0 &&
         env_var_buffer != nullptr) {
        input_parameter = static_cast<const wchar_t*>(env_var_buffer);
    }
}
```

### [Robust] Temp for whatever is accessible by your app (C++17)

```
#include <filesystem>
// ...
auto temp_path = std::filesystem::temp_directory_path().wstring();
```

[`temp_directory_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/temp_directory_path) will likely return the short name instead of the full name.

---

You're probably going to get the most use out of the first and last functions depending on your needs. If you're dealing with AppContainer apps, go for the last one provided by `<filesystem>`. It should return something like,

`C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Packages\{APP's GUID}\AC\Temp`

Answer (score 4):

Function **GetTempPath** will return a path with **a short name**,eg: `C:\Users\WDKREM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`.

To get **a full temp path name**,use **GetLongPathName** subsequently.

Answer (score 3):

Use GetTempPath() to retrieve the path of the directory designated for temporary files.

```
wstring TempPath;
wchar_t wcharPath[MAX_PATH];
if (GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, wcharPath))
   TempPath = wcharPath;
```

Comment: You should be able to just use `GetTempPath` instead of `GetTempPathW` or `GetTempPathA`. You're encouraged to not use WinAPIs with the `A` and `W` contexts directly, as it's supposed to detect if your project is ANSI or not and use the correct one based off of that. At the very least it will make your code more robust.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    std::cout << getenv("TEMP") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Won't that only work on Windows if it's in English or some set of Latin-character languages?

Answer (score 2):

GetTempPath isn't going to work on Vista unless the users have administrative access. I'm running into that problem right now with one of my apps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification
from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 2):

As VictorV pointed out, `GetTempPath` returns a collapsed path. You'll need to use both the `GetTempPathW` and `GetLongPathNameW` functions to get the fully expanded path.

```
[[noreturn]]
static void throw_error(const DWORD error)
{
    const std::error_code ec{ static_cast<int>(error), std::system_category() };
    throw std::system_error{ ec };
}

static std::wstring get_expanded_temp_path(const std::wstring_view collapsed)
{
    std::size_t count = GetLongPathNameW(collapsed.data(), nullptr, 0);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw_error(GetLastError());
    }

    std::wstring expanded(count, L'\0');

    count = GetLongPathNameW(
        collapsed.data(),
        expanded.data(),
        static_cast<DWORD>(expanded.size()));

    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw_error(GetLastError());
    }

    expanded.resize(count);
    return expanded;
}

static std::wstring get_temp_path()
{
    std::size_t count = GetTempPathW(0, nullptr);
    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw_error(GetLastError());
    }

    std::wstring collapsed(count, L'\0');   

    count = GetTempPathW(
        static_cast<DWORD>(collapsed.size()), 
        collapsed.data());

    if (count == 0)
    {
        throw_error(GetLastError());
    }

    collapsed.resize(count);
    return get_expanded_temp_path(collapsed);
}



int main() 
{
    const std::wstring expanded{ get_temp_path() };
    std::wcout << expanded << L'\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the Default constant `MAX_PATH`,  **Example** :

```
wchar_t defaultTempPath[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPathW(MAX_PATH, defaultTempPath);

// in case you return the result in a string function
return wstring(defaultTempPath);
```

In C++, `MAX_PATH` is a constant that represents the maximum length of a file path on the Windows operating system. It is defined as 260 characters, including the terminating null character.

The `MAX_PATH` constant is used in various `Win32 API` functions and structures that deal with **file paths**. It is important to note that this **limit applies specifically to the Windows API** and may not be applicable to other platforms or file systems .